# Resume windows update cleanup after reboot

Tags: windows-10

I have initiated Windows Update Cleanup from disk C properties \ Disk Cleanup. Disk Cleanup showed me that there are about 9 GB to clean. During cleanup process my computer rebooted because of the voltage drop while it cleaned only about 20%. After reboot there is no more option to start Windows Update cleanup from disk C properties, and I got only about 2 GB of extra free space instead of 9 GB.
How can I resume Windows Update clean up in case it was abnormally terminated?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the computer again to get a good startup.

Go to Admin Tools and select Disk Cleanup.

When the dialogue window comes up, select "Clean up system files"  lower left. Say OK to that. Then when the pre-cleanup has executed, say OK again to do the actual cleanup.

You can see how much space will be recovered when the pre-cleanup phase has finished.  Be sure to select all items for cleanup.

This process will re-run the disk cleanup for you after the prior shutdown.

Separately, get a small UPS as there are many reasons to avoid an abrupt power shutdown.